# Adding NSMutableDictionary with NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

My issue is trying to figure out how i would implement this procedure.

I have a Question List which will have strategies assigned to it and to the strategies there will be tools.

- Question 1

  - Strategy 1

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
    - Tool 3
  - Strategy 2

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
  - Strategy 3

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
    - Tool 3
    - Tool 4
- Question 2

  - Strategy 1

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
    - Tool 3
  - Strategy 2

    - Tool 1
  - Strategy 3

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
    - Tool 3

I want to implement this exactly like the example above but using NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary.

You can see that Every Question will have a strategy and every strategy will have at least 1 tool max of 5. As well a Question can have an unlimited amount of strategies.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I have looked online and cant seem to find any solid article on this so I would like to make this a solid answer for anyone else running into a complex array like this one.

Comment: "...that would be NSMutable."  NSMutable what?  Never mind...  I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: 'NSMutable' as opposed to 'NS', duh.

Comment: NSMutable meaning the objects within the array will not be static but dynamic and added and removed frequently. In this case the code section shows you that the QuestionList is NSMutableArray and the other two object within it will be NSMutableDictionary....i hope that clears that up for you @TBlue

Comment: Thanks for the lecture.  I happen to use NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary in every OSX application.  If your question were so clear, you probably wouldn't get 2 downvotes, none of which is mine yet.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary and Array objects can contain arbitrary objects.  Just create the objects you want and plug them together.  (Hint:  First figure out which of your concepts map to dictionaries and which map to arrays.  You'll likely find that a couple map to arrays of dictionaries.)

Comment: (You will not find a "formula" for this.  It's programming.  You have to design it, based on your requirements.  Forget the cookbook.)

Comment: (You might find it easier to map your concept first to JSON.  See json.org.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I see what you're trying to do here. So basically, you're trying to put an array of tools in each index of an array of strategies in each index of an array of questions. So something like:

- Question 1

  - Strategy 1

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
  - Strategy 2

    - Tool 1
- Question 2

  - Strategy 1

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
  - Strategy 2

    - Tool 1

The code should be something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *toolDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"tool1 info",@"tool1 key", @"tool2 info", @"tool2 key", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *stratDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:toolDict,toolDict,toolDict, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"strat1 key",@"strat2 key",@"strat3 key", nil]];

//loop through # of questions and add strat dict to each
NSMutableArray *QuestionList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < #ofQuestions; i++) {
    [QuestionList addObject:stratDict];
}
```

In this example, if you wanted to access tool 1 of strategy 1 in question 1 you would do:

```
[[[QuestionList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"strat1 key"] objectForKey:@"tool1 key"];
```

Comment: I got this in there but it shows up as Question 1 > Tool 1, Tool 2. No strategy.

Comment: That's a little strange. Are you sure you copied the code exactly? Can you post what you've done so far?

Comment: because of the length of code and most likely repeated contact can we finish this here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32516/adding-nsmutabledictionary-with-nsmutabledictionary-to-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 0):

In JSON:

```
[
  {"Question_id": "Question 1",
   "Strategies" : [
     {"Strategy_id" : "Strategy 1",
      "Tools" : [
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 1",
         "Tool_attr" : "sharp" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 2",
         "Tool_attr" : "dull" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 1",
         "Tool_attr" : "green" }
        ]
      },
     {"Strategy_id" : "Strategy 2",
      "Tools" : [
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 5",
         "Tool_attr" : "pointy" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 6",
         "Tool_attr" : "blunt" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 7",
         "Tool_attr" : "red" }
        ]
      }
    },
  {"Question_id": "Question 2",
   "Strategies" : [
     {"Strategy_id" : "Strategy 5",
      "Tools" : [
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 1",
         "Tool_attr" : "sharp" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 2",
         "Tool_attr" : "dull" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 1",
         "Tool_attr" : "green" }
        ]
      },
     {"Strategy_id" : "Strategy 6",
      "Tools" : [
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 5",
         "Tool_attr" : "pointy" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 6",
         "Tool_attr" : "blunt" },
        {"Tool_id" : "Tool 7",
         "Tool_attr" : "red" }
        ]
      }
   ]
```

This maps directly to NSDictionary/Array objects, where `{}` is a dictionary and `[]` is an array.

Comment: Thank you @HotLicks, this really does help me. You also proved the best point, i came into this industry to build and implement things i have not before and i am completely going around that method. There is no cookbook only a chef....Thank you!

Comment: @KeeanoMartin - Often times the biggest challenge in solving a problem is figuring out how to describe it.